# How to insert data into a Lookup Wizard column in Access via ODBC?

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

What is the SQL statement to insert data into a Lookup Wizard column in Microsoft Access via ODBC?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.
It is more likely to get an answer if you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Advise not to build lookups in table, build combobox on form. The RowSource would be a SELECT statement. Why are you using python and not just Access as gui and VBA to manage? Insert data into the field same as any field.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Access ODBC driver can insert into a *single-value* Lookup field by simply inserting the value.

```python
crsr.execute("INSERT INTO LookupTest (SingleValueLookupField) VALUES (?)", 'ListValue7')
```

The Microsoft Access ODBC driver **cannot** insert items into a *multi-value* Lookup field. To do that from Python you would need to use [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) and Access DAO, e.g.,

```python
import win32com.client

# ...

dbe = win32com.client.Dispatch("DAO.DBEngine.120")
db = dbe.OpenDatabase(r'C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb')

# adding multi-value items to an existing row in table [LookupTest]
rst_table = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM LookupTest WHERE ID=1", 2)  # dbOpenDynaset
rst_multivalue_lookup_field = rst_table.Fields('MultiValueFromList').Value
rst_table.Edit()
rst_multivalue_lookup_field.AddNew()
rst_multivalue_lookup_field.Fields('Value').Value = 'ListOption2'
rst_multivalue_lookup_field.Update()
rst_multivalue_lookup_field.AddNew()
rst_multivalue_lookup_field.Fields('Value').Value = 'ListOption5'
rst_multivalue_lookup_field.Update()
rst_table.Update()

db.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get this to work, but if you decide to change the database links (say from test to producton), you will lose the lookup information. Keep in mind that for any form, you can use the combo box wizard and get the SAME results and not have to add lookups at the table level. It is a VERY bad idea to attempt relational joins at the table level. Since users NEVER should edit the table(s) directly, but always use a form, or say a report, then the need for this feature and approach is not required. The combo box wizard on a form will do the SAME thing, and result in the same results. So that column should remain a standard long column datatype, and the combo box on a form will present the list from the other table, and grab + save the PK id from that other table.

As a result the ONLY advantage you get by using lookups at the table level is if you allow users to open + edit tables directly, and that as noted is a very bad idea. What happens if you need the ID of that column, but it is now returning some text because it is a lookup.

For any report, you can simple build a query, and join in the other table to provide the text description part in place of displaying the ID.

So I would strong recommend that you do not do this. As noted, because it is common to change what database the Access application points to, or even say change the name of the database server, then when you point (re-link) the tables in Access, you will lose the lookup settings.

Answer (score 0):

You won't use a 'Wizard' for this kind of thing.  Just code.

```
# insert data into 2 fields in a table    
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\your_path\\MSACCESS.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO Table2 (ExplodeKey, ExplodeField)
                    VALUES(5, 'RMS')  ''')

conn.commit()
```